# CFDOCUMENT PDF issues with word wrap and borders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I am trying to code a project where the user can add text to a template flyer and then create a pdf for print. I would like to use html elements instead of svg mostly because of ease of adding drag, resizing and word wrapping features. I then use cfdocument to create the pdf. The issue I am having is the word wrapping that is seen in the browser does not match the pdf. I also notice a border around the background image in the pdf. Does anyone know why either of these issues are happening? Thanks.

This is the browser view
[image: Browser view]

This is the pdf result. The pdf also has a white border around the image.
[image: pdf view]

The template is displayed via cfinclude.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="canvas">                          
  <cfinclude template="templates/T080764_1.htm">
</cfsavecontent>
<cfoutput>#canvas#</cfoutput>
```

Template code.

```
<img id="t0-1-img_1" class="item ui-resizable" style="left: 0px; top:  0px; width: 816px; height: 1056px; z-index: 1;" src="http://images/template-1.jpg" unselectable="true">
<div id="ti0-text_1" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:10px; width:450px; height:auto; text-align:left; font-family:Verdana; font-size:10pt; cursor:pointer; z-index: 2;"></div>
```

User clicks Add Text button and the text is added to the ti0-text_1 div with jquery.

```
$(function() { 
    $(".textbutton").click(function() {

        //straight text
        var txt = $("#text-field_1").html();
        $("#ti0-text_1").append(txt);           

    });
});
```

The canvas data is submitted via form to a page with the cfdocument code.

```
<cfdocument format="pdf" filename="pdf/#form.filename#" scale="100"  localurl="true" fontembed="yes" pageheight="11" pagewidth="8.50" unit="in" pagetype="custom"
 margintop="0" marginleft="0" marginright="0" marginbottom="0" overwrite="yes">
<cfoutput>#form.data#</cfoutput>
</cfdocument>
```

Comment: This must be tougher than I thought. I solved the border problem. I had a css class assigned to the background image that shouldn't have been.